# Reducing expression to simplest form involving variables in radicals

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

In my notebook, I obtain an expression that I can't figure out how to reduce to it's simplest form. I've recreated it below to show what I am trying to simplify.

```
Iratio2to1 = -(L1/Sqrt[L1 L2])
L2=(N2/N1)^2*L1 
Assuming[{L1, L2} > 0 && {L1, L2} \[Element] Reals,Cancel[Iratio2to1]]
```

this returns:

$$-\frac{L1}{4\sqrt{L1^2}}$$

I cannot figure out how to have Mathematica reduce this to $-\frac{1}{4}$.

I've tried [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html), [`Cancel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cancel.html), now [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)... I dont' get it!

Comment: Since `Greater` does not have the attribute `Listable` then `{L1, L2} > 0` does not do what you expect. Use either `L1 > 0 && L2 > 0` or `And@@Thread[{L1,L2} > 0]`. `Cancel` does not use the option `Assumptions` so the `Assuming` has no effect. Use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` since they use the option `Assumptions`. Any variable used in an inequality (e.g., `Greater`) is assumed real so the `{L1, L2} \[Element] Reals` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's equal to:

$$-\mathrm{sgn}(L1)\frac{1}{4}$$

You can approach in multiple ways:

Simplify for real `L1`:

```
FullSimplify[Iratio2to1, Element[L1, Reals]]
(* -(Sign[L1]/4) *)
```

Or for positive `L1`:

```
FullSimplify[Iratio2to1, L1 > 0]
(* -(1/4) *)
```

But for complex `L1` it won't cancel:

```
FullSimplify[Iratio2to1, Element[L1, Complexes]]
(* -(L1/(4 Sqrt[L1^2])) *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your `Assuming` doesn't work, but this works:

```
$Assumptions = L1 > 0

Simplify[-L1/(4 Sqrt[L1^2])]
(* -(1/4) *)
```